# Webkit adding unwanted, additional space above single text character

Tags: css, firefox, safari, webkit, gecko

Have a situation where I am adding a single character in a div with a button background. Seems pretty straight forward. However, the text placement is different between FF and Safari / Chrome. I created a basic page with one div and one character to illustrate the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .testDiv{
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                background: blue;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 50px;
                font-family: helvetica;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="testDiv">
    1
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fonts are rendered differently in just about every browser engine. Don't expect pixel-perfect results. Also, how do you know Webkit isn't accurate and FF is correct? Couldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Maybe line-height? I recommend using a REAL css reset

Answer (score 0):

WebKit and Mozilla appear to have a difference of opinion on how to treat line-height. The closest you are going to get this is to add line-height: 1; to your .testDiv rule, which will help a bit, before you have to start fudging around with webkit-specific properties.